# Scroll TextView like Marquee in android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, marquee

I am having a TextView and want to automatically scroll horizontally. i know it can be done using ellipsize property of text view. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ellipsize property of textView as follows

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"/>
```

Comment: In Activity you need to have this too:
`tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
tv.setSelected(true);`